# Cannot get Gridview header on PDF in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

I am trying to add pdf to my asp page, which takes value from Gridview onto the PDF. However, I can get all the values apart from Header. There seem to be a space on top but nothing there. 
I have practically copied the code from  [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-export-GridView-data-to-PDF-file-in-ASPNet.aspx).
My HTML markup is :

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="enrollecode" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="20">
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                    <Columns>

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enrolee Code" SortExpression="enrollecode">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblenrollecode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("enrollecode") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("enrollecode") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                  </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enrolee Name" SortExpression="enroleename">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblenroleename" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("enroleename") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("enroleename") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                  </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HMO" SortExpression="HMOName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblHMOName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HMOName") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("HMOName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                  </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Area Council" SortExpression="areacouncil">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblareacouncil" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("areacouncil") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("areacouncil") %>'></asp:Label>
                                  </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Main Hospital" SortExpression="mainhospital">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblmainhospital" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("mainhospital") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("mainhospital") %>'></asp:Label>
                                  </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Alt. Hospital" SortExpression="alternatehospital">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblalternatehospital" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("alternatehospital") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("alternatehospital") %>'></asp:Label>
                                  </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> 

                                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="D.O.B." SortExpression="Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbldob" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DOB","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("DOB","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                  </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> 

                                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                                             <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("enrollecode") %>' CommandName="View" ImageUrl="~/Image/8.png"  />

                                             </ItemTemplate>
                                         </asp:TemplateField>
                                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                             <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("enrollecode") %>' CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Image/editbutton.png"  />

                                             </ItemTemplate>
                                         </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("enrollecode") %>' CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Image/delete1.png" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do You Want to Delete?');" />

                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>



                                    </Columns>
                                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                                </asp:GridView>
```

And namespaces added :

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

My Codes:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                //To Export all pages
                GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                GridView1.ShowHeader = true;

                this.bindGV();

                GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();

                htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me using itextsharp 5.5.3

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Charset = string.Empty;
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Page.Response.Buffer = false;
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
    {
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.ShowHeader = true;
        this.bindGV();
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString()))
        {
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```